# The meaning of "yet" in "Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears had left the flushing in her galled eyes"

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> within a month;
>
> Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears
>
> Had left the flushing in her galled eyes,
>
> She married:

I'm wondering about the meaning of "yet" in the sentence above.

Comment: It means *yet.*

Comment: @CarSmack "Yet" has several meanings. I'm asking which one it has.

Comment: Well, I do not believe this website is meant to be a resource for explaining the language of *Hamlet.* There are probably websites that do that, and I know there are books that have plenty of notes on the play's language.

Comment: @CarSmack If asking about the archaic meaning of the word is off topic, why are there the tags "meaning" and "etymology"?

Comment: @CarSmack "I know there are books that have plenty of notes on the play's language."
OK. Could you tell me the name of such a book which explains the meaning of "yet" in the sentence?

Comment: @CarSmack "It means yet." If you don't know the answer, leave me alone, please.

Comment: Please leave the reason for the downvotes. Don't worry I won't revenge-downvote you.

Comment: CarSmack - what the heck is wrong with you today dude? Your points are bizarre.  *"Well, I do not believe this website is meant to be a resource for explaining the language of Hamlet"* Huh?  there are any number of questions on here about archaic language in Shakespeare.  It's the perfect example question for this site.

Comment: you can't actually "revenge-downvote" on these sites.  the system tracks people who go from a question, to a user's page, and then down votes.  basically you cannot sequentially down vote (or indeed up vote) another user.

Comment: This is sense 3c of *yet* in the OED: "With *ere, before,* etc. indicating the ultimate occurrence of something after an interval of time: before *ere,* etc., nearly = ‘already’; after *ere,* etc., nearly = ‘at length’ (cf. 5 a). Now only in ***ere yet*** (arch.)."

Comment: I think, if you had only said what you *thought* the phrase containing "yet" meant, then everybody would have been happier. It's obvious that you are studying the text in detail, so why not sure some of your insights and findings. I wish I could help, but poetry/prose is lost on me. Which doesn't mean I don't find the answers fascinating and enlightening.

Comment: (Typo) I think, if you had only said what you thought the phrase containing "yet" meant, then everybody would have been happier. It's obvious that you are studying the text in detail, so why not **SHARE** some of your insights and findings. I wish I could help, but poetry/prose is lost on me. Which doesn't mean I don't find the answers fascinating and enlightening

Comment: Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears//Had left the flushing in her galled eyes=Even before the salt of her tears had been flushed out of her eyes, which were hurting.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to change the word order of a puzzling and/or archaic sentence when you're trying to work out the exact significance of its individual elements. (This is particularly so with poetry, where the poet may have moved a word from its expected position in a sentence in order to accommodate the dictates of metre and scansion.) Updating the vocabulary can also help.

For instance, here we can take the original,

> Within a month; // Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears // Had left the flushing in her galled eyes, // She married:

and tweak it to produce the following:

> Within a month, before the salt of [her] most unrighteous tears had **yet** left the flushing [I assume this means 'redness'] in her galled eyes, she married:

According to the 1828 Websters, [*galled*](http://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/galled) means "Having the skin or surface worn or torn by wearing or rubbing; fretted; teased; injured; vexed".

If we disregard considerations of linguistic beauty and focus purely on updating the language even further and removing distracting ornamentation in order to clarify the exact meaning, we might end up with something like this:

> Before her insincere tears had **even** left the eyes which she had rubbed red, within a month she had married:

Still today, you could render this using 'yet' instead of 'even':

> Before her insincere tears had **yet** left the eyes which she had rubbed red, within a month she had married:

But I think you'd run the risk of sounding rather old-fashioned if you did.

**Edit**

(Just to spell it out, in this context **yet = even.**)

Alternatively, you could rephrase my version thus:

> Her insincere tears had not even left the eyes that she had rubbed red, when within a month she had married:

Comment: EK, your long answer is fantastic, but the question is simply **what's the YET mean**.

Comment: FTR I had utterly no clue what you meant for "yet"!  :)  BTW, pointing out that yet can be used (even today) to mean "even" is a great point; I hadn't thought of it.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I've updated my answer to incorporate my clarifications.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think OP didn't realize that `yet` was supposed to go with "Had left the flushing in her galled eyes," and was trying to make sense of the combination "Ere yet", hence the question *what does yet mean [in "Ere yet"]*.

Comment: Where's the answer? I think it means: even before.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't add any meaning - "Ere the salt... had left" would mean the same - but it does add a bit of emphasis to "ere", and more importantly it pads out the meter, so that "Ere yet" has the same rhythm as "Had left" in the next line.

Comment: Even before is what it means.

Comment: Yes - but the "even" in "even before" doesn't add any meaning.  Slight emphasis - which is exactly what I said in my answer - but no change in meaning.

Comment: You don't actually say what it means in your answer.  You keep saying "it" and you don't break it down.

Comment: 1) That's an interesting objection, considering how your initial comment was worded: "Even before is what it means."  2) My answer was a direct response to the last sentence of the OP's question: "I'm wondering about the meaning of 'yet' in the sentence above."  3) The word "yet" does have meaning, it's true.  But in this sentence, it does not actually add meaning - it is only an intensifier.  Which is what I said in the first place.  Reading comprehension - it's A Thing.

Comment: Question: What is "yet"? Answer: "ere yet" here forms a "unit" to mean "even before".

Comment: For the love of Roget, we GET IT.  "Ere" means "before"; "ere yet" means "even before".  But - without resorting to a circular definition - what change in meaning is there between "ere" and "ere yet", and between "before" and "even before"?  I say that the difference is of emphasis only - no extra meaning is conveyed by the extra word.  And I said this in my original answer.  You may disagree, but to convince me you'll need to do more than repeat synonyms.  If you, like the words "yet" and "even", have nothing more to say...

Comment: The difference is emphasis. I agree with that. I just think your explanation is not great.

Answer (score 0):

From Hamlet

Within a month.

***Ere yet*** the salt of most unrighteous tears

Had left the flushing in her galled eyes,
She married.

***Even before*** the salt of her crocodile tears had been washed out of her sore eyes, she married.

Coriolanus:

See here these movers that do prize their hours 
At a crack'd drachm! Cushions, leaden spoons, 
Irons of a doit, doublets that hangmen would 
Bury with those that wore them, these base slaves, 
***Ere yet*** the fight be done, pack up: down with them!

***Even before*** the fight is done.

Henry the Fifth:

But, by the mass, our hearts are in the trim; 
And my poor soldiers tell me, **yet ere night**

**Even before** night falls

Together, ere plus yet means: even before

OLD hymn:
1 Ere yet the dawn hath filled the skies, = Even before

Behold my Savior Christ arise;

He chaseth from us sin and night

And brings us joy and life and light.

Hallelujah!

[enter link description here](https://hymnary.org/text/ere_yet_the_dawn_hath_filled_the_skies)

[ere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ere)